# How do you save an HTML5 <canvas> as an ICO image (icon file) or a .cur file (static mouse cursor) rather than a PNG in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I've been searching for how to save an HTML5 `<canvas>` element as a .ico image or a .cur file (static mouse cursor file) on [Google](https://www.google.com/), but I'm getting results for how to save as a PNG, not another format. What do I do in JavaScript to save a `<canvas>` as an image in any format other than PNG? (e.g. JPEG, BMP, GIF, ICO)

Comment: You have to pass the correct mime type to the toBlob and other methods, eg `image/jpeg` but the browser has to support that format if it doesnt it defaults to the png format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [an example at MDN - A way to convert a canvas to an ico](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) which might help you. It says Mozilla only, but suggests that other browsers might be made to work.

Comment: I sure hope it works in [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)!